# Android App Release Questions

Tags: android, google-play, release

I had some doubt regarding android app release,

please respond me as soon as possible.

**1.** How long it will take for app review in google play ?

**2.** How soon my app will appear in play store after review ?

**3.** Can i update my app while app is being reviewed ?

**4.** How can let the user know about app supporting android OS ?

Comment: 5.Will review process held for each app update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How long it will take for app review in google play?

Usually just a few hours, there is no fixed amount of time, in my experience about 6 hours was the maximum

> How soon my app will appear in play store after review?

There will be no separate update to inform you that the review is done, its all seamless you publish the app, google will review and put it on playstore.

> Can i update my app while app is being reviewed?

Yes, google will just stop the review for your previous apk(? not sure about hopefully someone will correct me on this), but most certainly they will start the process flow of their review process to the latest apk you uploaded

> How can let the user know about app supporting android OS?

If your app isn't supporting some android OSes, then your app wont be available in the play store for that OS, but they will still see your app in the web, but when they try to install the app on their device through web, incompatible device error will be shown

**EDIT**

> Will review process held for each app update?

yes every apk upload will go through the review process flow

Comment: @MAREESKANNNANR yes every apk upload will go through review process flow

Answer (score 4):

1. Google Play doesn't review your app prior to release really like Apple does, so it's very rapid, like 2 to 3 hours after you submit the app.
2. See above: your app will appear in Google Play Store 2 to 3 hours after you submit it to Google Play.
3. If you're really that quick, sure!
4. Wut? If you mean the Android Level supported y your app, that information goes in the manifest.xml and Google Play Store will check for compatibility with the device before allowing the user to download.

Releasing through Google Play Store is extremely easy! Good luck!

Comment: There is still a review process though, where they look for copyrighted images, malicious behaviour in your app, usually they just do it through a machine, but still the app is reviewed

Comment: I stand corrected. Also be aware that Google is currently cracking down on shady monetizing practices and may be looking closely at your app during the first month or two that it is on the store. You should check [HERE](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) to be sure you meet Google's policies before submitting an app.

Comment: It takes about the same amount of time each new APK so I suspect the process is the same for an update as it is for the initial listing.